# How to keep LGAlertView shown after button is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have the delegate set as self and added

also here is my code:

```
LGAlertView *alertView = [[LGAlertView alloc]initWithViewAndTitle:@"title" message:nil style:LGAlertViewStyleActionSheet view:view buttonTitles:@[@"Button 1"] cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
            actionHandler:^(LGAlertView *alertView, NSString *title, NSUInteger index)
        {
        NSLog(@"actionHandler, %@, %lu", title, (long unsigned)index);
        }
        cancelHandler:^(LGAlertView *alertView) {
        NSLog(@"cancelHandler");
        }
        destructiveHandler:^(LGAlertView *alertView) {
        NSLog(@"destructiveHandler");
        }];

        [buyView setCancelOnTouch:NO];

        [buyView setDelegate:self];

        NSLog(@"%d",buyView.cancelOnTouch);
        [buyView showAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];
```

When i do press on a button it still dismisses the view

also when the view is dismissed this shows up on the logs `-[LGAlertView dealloc] [Line 972]`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to set `alert.dismissOnAction = NO;`